# SQL query that generates another SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Our product has two parts, a server application and a client application.  The server application uses SQL server as the database engine.  The client application uses SQL Anywhere.  Data on the server replicates to the client using our proprietary replication scheme.

We recently had a problem at a client which caused us headaches.  We've fixed the issue with that customer, but I want to produce a tool that we can use to find rows in the Users table that could be the cause of the problem.

We have a number of tables in the server application's database that keep track of the data that needs to be replicated to the clients.  What these tables are and how they are layed out is irrelevant to this question.

I want to write a query in SQL Server that we can run and whose output is a query that the tech support guys can just copy to their clipboard and paste it into a remote session with the SQL Anywhere database query tool on the client.  This is not hard to do, the problem is that that there may be more than one row in the client that needs to be checked.

The query I have looks something like this:

```
SELECT 'SELECT Id, Name FROM MyClientTable WHERE <Condition to identify problem rows> AND Id = ''' + CONVERT( nvarchar(36), Id ) + '''' 
FROM MyServerTable
WHERE <Condition to identify problem row candidates>
```

This produces one query for each candidate row.  I want one query that looks more like:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM MyClientTable WHERE <condition to identify problem rows> AND ID IN ( . . . )
```

Is there a way that I can pull this off?  If so, just how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
DECLARE @Tsql VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @Tsql = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM MyClientTable WHERE <condition to identify problem rows> AND ID IN ('

SELECT @Tsql = @Tsql + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) + ','
FROM MyServerTable
WHERE <Condition to identify problem row candidates>

--Remove last trailing comma, append closing parentheses.
SELECT @Tsql = LEFT(@Tsql, LEN(@Tsql) - 1) + ')'

PRINT @Tsql
```

**Edit:** tsql changes for compatibility with older versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query

```
;WITH Ids(IdValues)
AS
(
    SELECT '''' + CAST (Id AS VARCHAR(39)) + ''',' AS 'text()'   
    FROM MyServerTable WHERE <Condition to identify problem row candidates>
    FOR XML Path('')
)
SELECT 'SELECT Id, Name FROM MyClientTable WHERE <Condition to identify problem rows> AND Id IN (' + LEFT(IdValues,LEN(IdValues)-1) + ')' 
FROM Ids;
```